# Generate a unique slug on mongoose schema.pre.('update')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to generate an slug when update is called in mongoose, now I have this and it works.

```
schema.pre('update', function (next) {
    const title = this._update.$set['title']
    this._update.$set['slug'] = slugify(title.toLowerCase())
    next()
})
```

The problem is that **slug** is a **unique: true** field so if add two posts with the same title I get an error, for example like this:

```
"slug: post-2\" already exists."
```

So now before calling **next()** I want to be sure if my slug already exists calling find, now I have this code:

```
.pre('update', function (next) {
    const title = this._update.$set['title']
    this._update.$set['slug'] = slugify(title.toLowerCase())

    this._find({ slug }, function (err, docs) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err)
        else
            console.log(docs)
        next()
    })
})
```

But when is called I get the following error:

```
          ? callback(null, docs)
            ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
```

How should I continue?

Answer (score 2):

Code looks much better without callbacks with async / await instead:

```
schema.pre('update', async function() {
    //...
    let doc = await this.model.findOne({/* some filter */});
    //...
    this.update({}, { $set:{ slug } });
});
```

Also consider there can be no _id, or update can affect multiply documents.
It's also can be creation of new doc with `upsert` option.

I'd recommend to use some [existing solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-slug-updater):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    slug = require('mongoose-slug-updater'),
    mongoose.plugin(slug),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    schema = new Schema({
        title: String,
        slug: { type: String, slug: "title", unique: true }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
// uniq slug generator function, converts `text` to `text1` if `text` exists 
schema.statics.generateSlug = function(text, suffix, callback){
    var _this = this;
    var possibleText = text + (suffix || '');
    _this.findOne({
        slug: slugify(possibleText.toLowerCase())
    }, function(err, item){
        if(!err) {
            if(!item) {
                callback(possibleText);
            } else {
                return _this.generateSlug(text, (suffix || 0) + 1, callback);
            }
        } else {
            callback(null);
        }
    });
};

schema.pre('update', function (next) {
    var _this = this;
    const title = _this._update.$set['title'];
    _this.generateSlug(title, null, function(possibleSlug) {
        if (possibleSlug) {
             _this._update.$set['slug'] = possibleSlug;
             next();
        } else return next(new Error('No possible slug'));

    });
})
```

Comment: This works, but with this solution every time you update the same post and the title is the same is going to add to the slug _1 even if there is no other post that has the same slug.

Before adding the suffix it has to check if the found slug is from other post, how I can achieve this?

Comment: Okay this is my solution for avoiding to change the slug if it's not necessary. [I tried to remove this comment but I can't, I'm going to post the code in other comment]

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for avoiding to change the slug if it's not necessary

```
Post.statics.slugify = function (next) {
    const title = this._update.$set['title']
    const _id = this._conditions['_id']

    const that = this
    this.model.slugify(title, _id, null, slug => {
        that._update.$set['slug'] = slug
        next()
    })
}

Post.pre('validate', function (text, _id, suffix, cb) {
    const field = text + (suffix || '')
    const slug = Slugify(field.toLowerCase())

    const that = this
    that.findOne({ slug }, (err, item) => {
        if (!err) {
            if (item)
                // Checks if current document has already the currect slug
                if (`${ item._id }` === `${ _id }`)
                    cb(slug)
                else
                    return that.slugify(`${ text }`, _id, (suffix || 0) + 1, cb)
            else
                cb(slug)
        }
        else
            cb(null)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it this way:

```js
const getUniqueSlug = (value, valueList, index = 0) => {
  if (!valueList.length || valueList.indexOf(value) < 0) {
    return value;
  }
  if (valueList.indexOf(`${value}-${index + 1}`) < 0) {
    return `${value}-${index + 1}`;
  }
  return getUniqueValue(value, valueList, index + 1);
}

schema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (!this.slug || !this.slug.length) {
    this.slug = slugify(this.title.toLowerCase());
  }
  const usedSlugsList = await this.constructor.distinct('slug', {
    _id: { $ne: this._id },
    slug: {
      $regex: `^${this.slug}`,
      $options: 'i',
    },
  });
  if (usedSlugsList.length) {
    this.slug = getUniqueSlug(this.slug, usedSlugsList);
  }

  next();
});
```

Hope it would be helpful for someone.